# failure playback of youtube videos

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

when I try to playback youtube videos sometimes get a notice about downloading latest version of flash playback software. After setting the software up I still fail to playback youtube videos.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably not be playing youtube videos on TOR. you tube uses flash, and its suggested not to use Flash websites/products as they could expose your identity/ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make comments yet, and this isn't exactly an answer.

Tbb supports html5, and many youtube videos can be played in html5 (allegedly)

https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=GB

so you may not even need flash

Answer (score 0):

The YT html5 page says my Tor browser supports html5 BUT nothing works!  All vids give this error message:

Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.
Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about html5 video.

Been there several times and the page always tells me the browser supports:
HTMLVideoELement
Media Source Extensions
MSE and WebM and VP9
The HTML5 player is currently used when possible.

I have tried several different Firefox extensions that allegedly enable html5 BUT NOTHING WORKS!!!

I do research and must play and review many videos daily.  A real pain to have to use another browser to do so, to copy and paste the url elesewhere.  Besides, I want to dump Chrome ASAP, as it is horrible.  But now have to keep it open for videos!  Which are choppy there.

Please, how can I play videos in Tor???

Comment: If playback is choppy even *without* Tor then it's possible the issue isn't Tor Browser.